# Is there a way that QDockWidget can set independent arbitrary position?

Tags: css, qt, user-interface, dock, qdockwidget

- picture 1:[the current way of dock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgvgp.png)
- picture 2:[the way I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvNvv.png)

As you can see, picture 1 shows how QDockWidget sets position, when I resize the dock1's height, dock2 changes too, same as dock3 and dock4. And picture 2 is what I want, I change dock1's size, it doesn't influence dock2's size and position. So is there a way that make it ?

Comment: `QDockWidget`s are placed around a central widget. Where should be this central widget in your pictures?